# Нарушается порядковый номер при удалении строки

Tags: c#, база-данных

Имеется приложение, которое соединяется с БД Access. В DataGridView выводится одна из таблиц, DataGridView соединен с bindingnavigator'ом. При удалении из таблицы последней строки (допустим было 5 строк, удалили одну последнюю, стало 4) и последующем добавлении новой, порядковый номер идёт в таком порядке, как-будто строку не удалили ( 6 вместо 5). Подскажите, как исправить этот момент.

Загрузка БД:

```
 private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "spectr2DataSet.Тестовый_участок". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
        this.тестовый_участокTableAdapter.Fill(this.r2DataSet.Тестовый_участок);

    }
```

Обновление:

```
  private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.тестовый_участокTableAdapter.Update(this.r2DataSet.Тестовый_участок);
    }
```

Comment: Распространённое заблуждение. Автоинкрементный первичный ключ не является порядковым номером и не должен таковым считаться.

Comment: Поспешил с вопросом. Как я понял, это неизбежно и обнулить счётчик можно только непосредственно вручную в БД. Удалите или закройте вопрос, спасибо!

Comment: Я знаю, это никак не влияет на работу БД, просто выглядит не так красиво, когда после 4 идёт 6 номер.

Comment: Вопрос удалять не надо, этот вопрос может быть помощью для других участников сообщества.

Answer (score 2):

Это стандартное поведение базы данных, для первичного ключа счётчик инкрементируется, но при удалении записей, образуются пустоты в нумерации. Если вы хотите завести числовой порядковый номер, то для этой цели можно ввести отдельный столбец в котором этот номер будет вычисляться.

Но опять же не очень понятно зачем нужна непрерывная нумерация, так как это дополнительная нагрузка на вычислении, а при удалении средних записей придётся сдвигать всю нумерацию дальше.

Answer (score 0):

Это не оптимально.

Сами приставьте: у вас идут параллельные запросы и что-то удаляется|добавляется и вы хотите повесить дополнительную логику на заполнение пробелов в нумерации.

При сдвиге порядковых номеров после удаления, вы будете блокировать строки.

Даже если вы не будете двигать, а будете добавлять новые строки на место удаленных, то это тоже снизит производительность, так как будет тратится время на поиск свободной строки.

Вывод: Лучше уйти от этого либо реализуйте этот функционал ручками в виде каких-нибудь триггеров.

Красота там должна быть в меру и не должна идти в разрез с производительностью.